# Blender > Unity Animation Export (Missing Actions)

Tags: animation, export, unity

I'm trying to export my rigged character animations to Unity. But, there are always lots of missing actions that don't seem to make it to Unity. Here's a picture showing my settings and workflow.  I've tried every possible combination of settings I could think of, but to no avail:
[image]

AND, just in case it helps, here's a download link to the file in case anyone wants to test things for themselves: [Link-HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1REi6-9bLKs3hE9JsyLYOCwu1DRH0E0Bu/view?usp=sharing)

Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to bring the blender file itself into unity instead of exporting as fbx or just save it to the assets folder i think it works the same way

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use NLA, in Unity if you have missing animations and the fbx have the animations, you can go to + to add a new animation and in source take reamplace with the missed animation